# matplotlib subplot with image background

Tags: matplotlib, png, subplot

how can I create a subplot, where the background is created fully, without a gray boundry, with a png image from file.png

I have tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
im = plt.imread('map.gif')
implot = plt.imshow(im,aspect='auto',origin='lower')
fig0=implot.figure.tight_layout(pad=0.5)
implot.axes.set_axis_off()
fig1=implot.figure

ax1=fig1.add_subplot(2,2,1)

ax1.plot(range(10))
ax2=fig1.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax2.plot(range(9,-1,-1))

plt.show()
```

I cannot get the image to span the whole graphics window

thanks

Ilan

Comment: What have you tried? You should include the code you have so far. You are much more likely to get good answers if you show the effort you have put into solving this problem yourself.

Comment: I have an answer for this question, which no longer seems off-topic now that code has been added, but can't post it owing to it being on-hold.

Comment: @ConstantineEvans It is unfortunate, but there are not currently enough re-open votes

Comment: I have updated my question in line with your comments. please remove from on hold status

Comment: This is ridiculous, as it is actually quite a good question. In order to have the image span the whole window, you need to create the axes manually so that space isn't left on the sides for the tick labels. Eg, try `fig = plt.figure(); ax = plt.Axes(fig,[0,0,1,1]); fig.add_axes(ax); ax.set_axis_off(); ax.imshow(im,aspect='auto'); plt.show()`.